# Having issues on my image slider, and really not sure why

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Trying to do an image slider but nothing works. I am having so much difficulty with something that everyone keeps saying pretty easy to do. I been going along with this tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KcdBOoK3Pfw&list=WL&index=19&t=601s

Yet the button doesn't seem to work. The Images wont fit inside. I don't care if three of them show up at this point I just want it to work.

The images won't just go into the container. They all go in. The 2 in one wasn't my intention. I wanted one pic than the next pic shows.

I'm still pretty new to this. So probably will keep on trying and trying and understanding but trying to finish this for a personal project. Can anyone help out and explain to me what I am doing wrong.

HERE IS MY CODE:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gallery.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <div class="slide">
    <img src="./image/pic7.jpg" id="lastClone">
    
    <img src="image/pic1.jpg">
    
    <img src="image/pic2.jpg">
    
    <img src="image/pic3.jpg">
    
    <img src="image/pic4.jpg">

    
    <img src="image/pic6.jpg">
    
    <img src="image/pic7.jpg">
    <img src="./image/pic1.jpg" id="firstclone">
    </div>  
</div>

<button id="prevbtn">Prev</button>
<button id="nextbtn">Next</button>

<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 40%;
    margin:auto;
    border: 5px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
    
   
}

.slide {
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    
}


button{
    padding:20px;
    border:none;
    background:#37f;
    font-size: 30px;
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
}


#nextbtn{
    border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    margin-left:950px;
}
#prevbtn{
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
const carouselSlide =docuement.querySelector('.slide');
const carouselImages=document.querySelectorAll('.slide img');

const prevbtn = document.querySelector('#prevbtn');
const nextbtn = document.querySelector('#nextbtn');

let counter=1;
const size=carouselImages[0].clientWidth;

carouselSlide.style.transform='translateX(' + (-size *counter) + 'px)';



nextbtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    if (counter >= carouselImages.length-1) return;
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
    counter ++;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

});


prevbtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    if (counter <= 0) return;
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
    counter ++;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

});

carouselSlide.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    if (carouselImages[counter].id=='lastClone') {
        carouselSlide.style.transition = "none";
        counter=carouselImages.length -2;
        carouselSlide.style.transform= 'translateX(' +(-size * counter) + 'px)';
    }

    
    if (carouselImaages[counter].id=='firstClone') {
            carouselSlide.style.transition = "none";
            counter=carouselImaages.length -counter;
            carouselSlide.style.transform= 'translateX(' +(-size * counter) + 'px)';
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well right off the bat you have spaces between the counters and '++' on the event listeners, so that's not gonna work.

Some unsolicited advice: 9/10 when I was a beginner programmer it was a typo that was causing my frustrations or something missing. Before getting frustrated take a step back and look for such things.

Comment: But why can't I click on the next and prev button?